# Why does git rebase fall out of memory, while cherry-pick works?

Tags: git

Sometimes `rebasing` commits, that are huge (talking way beyond 100MB), git hits its memory limit and aborts. The strange thing is, when I `cherry-pick` these commits one by one it works fine.

I previously thought, that `rebase` would mostly do a `cherry-pick` in the background, but it seems like I was wrong. What does `rebase` do differently, that it consumes to much memory?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `cherry-pick` takes a commit (think of this as a single patch file with all the changes that commit did) and applies that to the current state of another branch.

`rebase` takes your branch, rolls back all unmerged commits, updates your branch with the one you're rebasing on, and reapplies all the unmerged commits you had. I would guess it keeps the rolled back commits in memory during this process. Depending on the nature and size of the unmerged commits this might be substantial.

In any case, I would consider this a bug in git, and if you could pinpoint what it is making git abort, that could help handling these kinds of cases.